# Find replies on Slack direct message

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm dumping my direct messages in Slack.
I manage to get all the messages one by one.
However I don't find any property that tells which message is a parent message and which ones are replies.
How can we get this information?

Typical code in C#

```
ConversationsListResponse conversationListRespons = await slackClient.GetConversationsListAsync("",false,100,types);
foreach (var channel in conversationListRespons.channels)
{        
    ConversationsMessageHistory messages = await slackClient.GetConversationsHistoryAsync(channel);
```

Even when I test the api from the slack interface, it's not giving the information.
Are there any other apis than the ones I'm using to get the required information?

Api used: https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history

Here is an example: This a main Direct Message with 4 replies.
conversations.history returns them without any relationship between them.

[image]

The query in slack test interface:

[image]

and the result:

```html
{
    "ok": true,
    "messages": [
        {
            "type": "message",
            "text": "voici un log",
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": "F04M6EAEXGX",
                    "created": 1675280228,
                    "timestamp": 1675280228,
                    "name": "32x32.ico",
                    "title": "32x32.ico",
                    "mimetype": "application/octet-stream",
                    "filetype": "binary",
                    "pretty_type": "Binary",
                    "user": "U0XNQGD0R",
                    "user_team": "T0XN0RW8H",
                    "editable": false,
                    "size": 4286,
                    "mode": "hosted",
                    "is_external": false,
                    "external_type": "",
                    "is_public": false,
                    "public_url_shared": false,
                    "display_as_bot": false,
                    "username": "",
                    "url_private": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T0XN0RW8H-F04M6EAEXGX/32x32.ico",
                    "url_private_download": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T0XN0RW8H-F04M6EAEXGX/download/32x32.ico",
                    "media_display_type": "unknown",
                    "permalink": "https://sanitized.slack.com/files/U0XNQGD0R/F04M6EAEXGX/32x32.ico",
                    "permalink_public": "https://slack-files.com/T0XN0RW8H-F04M6EAEXGX-bb8c68eec7",
                    "is_starred": false,
                    "has_rich_preview": false,
                    "file_access": "visible",
                    "media_progress": null
                }
            ],
            "upload": false,
            "user": "U0XNQGD0R",
            "display_as_bot": false,
            "ts": "1675280236.783609",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text",
                    "block_id": "Twy",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": "voici un log"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "client_msg_id": "5bda3f9c-64a8-4c1b-8b5e-f37c3b2e2c5d"
        },
        {
            "client_msg_id": "850f4ecc-59c0-4af0-b13f-e527ed7a88de",
            "type": "message",
            "text": "<@U0XNQ04JD> test",
            "user": "U0XNQGD0R",
            "ts": "1675280205.367429",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text",
                    "block_id": "qi/vH",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "user",
                                    "user_id": "U0XNQ04JD"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": " test"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "team": "T0XN0RW8H"
        },
        {
            "client_msg_id": "e249a07d-f887-4edb-859a-1cc38559dc7b",
            "type": "message",
            "text": ":100:",
            "user": "U0XNQGD0R",
            "ts": "1675280190.138859",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text",
                    "block_id": "rGp",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "emoji",
                                    "name": "100",
                                    "unicode": "1f4af"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "team": "T0XN0RW8H"
        },
        {
            "client_msg_id": "df2a2f63-21b1-42d5-91db-3c66b083ed7c",
            "type": "message",
            "text": "yes<https://www.google.com|link to google>",
            "user": "U0XNQGD0R",
            "ts": "1675280183.929889",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text",
                    "block_id": "GZV",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": "yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "link",
                                    "url": "https://www.google.com",
                                    "text": "link to google"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "team": "T0XN0RW8H",
            "reactions": [
                {
                    "name": "+1",
                    "users": [
                        "U0XNQGD0R"
                    ],
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "client_msg_id": "116e4fc3-ef4a-4148-84ad-975ff0f227e6",
            "type": "message",
            "text": "Salut Christophe,\nthis is a test for Slack",
            "user": "U0XNQGD0R",
            "ts": "1675254487.545169",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text",
                    "block_id": "O2s",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "rich_text_section",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": "Salut ,\nthis is a test for Slack"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "team": "T0XN0RW8H"
        }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "is_limited": false,
    "pin_count": 0,
    "channel_actions_ts": null,
    "channel_actions_count": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, there might be some confusion as to what constitutes a reply or thread on Slack. Your first screenshot seems like several "normal" messages posted by the same user one after the other. In Slack a thread is a message posted by selecting the thread icon that corresponds to a parent message as seen in the screenshot.[image]

With that established, you can retrieve threaded messages by making a call to [conversations.replies](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.replies).

Answer (score 0):

The SlackAPI is lacking this functionality as I'm seeing it.
The way you can do this in C# is as follows:

*Define a custom class where you define it needs to call conversations.replies:*

```
[RequestPath("conversations.replies", true)]
class GetConversationRepliesResult : Response
{
    public List<SlackAPI.Message> messages;
}
```

Call the Slack API using this custom class:

```
var replies = await client.APIRequestWithTokenAsync<GetConversationRepliesResult>(new [] {
    Tuple.Create("channel", channelId),
    Tuple.Create("ts", messageTS),
});
```